# Email bitmap image in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make it so upon clicking a button, my app takes a screenshot of the current screen programmatically and stores it in a variable (this I have managed to do). I would then want it to send an email, attaching that bitmap image to it.

(I have tried hard coding the email address etc in)

When I have tried to send an email with simple text for the body it has worked fine, but when I try to attach an image it doesn't work.

```
 Button emailBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailBtn);
 main = findViewById(R.id.main);//email form button
        emailBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bitmap b = screenshot.takescreenshotOfRootView(main);
                //ImageView programLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.programLogo);
                //programLogo.setImageBitmap(b);
                String subject = "please work";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                        "mailto","myemail@gmail.com", null));
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, b);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email client :"));
                }
        });
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.computingproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Computing Project"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Main11Activity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main10Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main9Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main8Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main7Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main6Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main5Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main4Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main3Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Screenshot.java

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;

public class screenshot {

    public static Bitmap takescreenshot(View v) {
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        v.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return b;
    }

    public static Bitmap takescreenshotOfRootView(View v) {
        return takescreenshot(v.getRootView());
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: [EXTRA_STREAM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) is the way to go. 
You should consider to use it with [ACTION_SEND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) or [ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) instead as those are documented in detail.

Comment: @hartwecm do you mean replacing EXTRA_TEXT with EXTRA_STREAM and replacing ACTION_SENDTO with ACTION_SEND? Because upon doing so the program crashes once I press the button to activate this sequence.